# Zend include template file in another template

Tags: templates, zend-framework

I want to include a template file in another template file so I can get variable values.
Like I have two files **_template1.phtml** and **template2.phtml**

In **_template1.phtml** I have:

```
$this->text[] = 'Text here';
```

In **template2.phtml** I want to access the value of `"text"`. I tried

```
$this->render('folder/template2.phtml');
var_dump($text);
var_dump($this->text);
```

but neither of this works.

What I need is _template1 file would be included from the template so the scope of $this would be the view object.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I can use [Partial Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.partial) to pass variables from one view to another

Comment: Thanks, partial works for me with some tweaks. Not sure what I was missing so render isn't working.